# Is there a way to access text messages or call data (Like call history) from the SDK?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5

I was wondering if there was a way to access the data to sent/received text messages from the SDK and if this behavior is approved for the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, this is not accessible.